# Run a Program even if in system tray vb.net

Tags: vb.net, background, system-tray, notifyicon

*I have a program that copies files from one directory to the other. I want it to run when minimised and an icon should show in the system tray so I created these codes. The minimise and system tray icon shows but AS SOON AS IT IS MINIMISED, THE COPYING SEIZES. I want the process to continue when the form is minimised. Please Help.

```
Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    If Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized Then
        Notif.Visible = True
        Notif.BalloonTipText = "Copying"
        Notif.BalloonTipTitle = "Serious Copying"
        Notif.ShowBalloonTip(5000)
        Notif.Text = "Serious Copying"
        ShowInTaskbar = False
        Me.Visible = False

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub notifycn1_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles notifycn1.DoubleClick
    Me.Visible = True
    Me.show()
    ShowInTaskbar = True
    Notif.Visible = False
    Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
End Sub
```

Comment: There's more to this than what you posted. I can create a new program minimize it and still move files just fine. The code above would and should not stop your process ***unless you are throwing an exception*** or you are ***doing something else that you are not showing***.

Comment: Delete the ShowInTaskbar assignments.  They are unnecessary, the taskbar button is already invisible when you hide the window.  And they are dangerous, the property is a "difficult" one that requires recreating the native window.  Which gets the Resize event to fire over and over again, looks like it "stops copying".

Comment: @Codexer . Can you further explain **throwing exception**? as for hiding something, I be mocking myself to do that. Please help if you can. Hans  Passant I took of the ShownInTaskbar but the problem was not resolved.

Comment: @MordC if your app throws an exception and if not handled correctly or just swallowed up it can stop execution of the process. The code as already mentioned above will **not stop the copying of files**. You have other code you are not showing that probably is the culprit...